# How to include previous/next inputs in quadratic cost function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

I have a path of state vectors where each state vector consist on:

$$ \underline{x} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  x_{trailer}\\
  y_{trailer}\\
  \theta_{trailer}
\end{array}
\right] $$
$$ \underline{u} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \kappa_{trailer}\\
  \Delta_{s}
\end{array}
\right] $$

I want to smooth my current path making use of iLQR and for that I have defined my cost function as:
$$
J = \sum_{\tau=0}^{N-1}l(x_{i},u_{i})+l_{f}(x_{N})
$$
$$
l(x_{i},u_{i})= W_u \cdot u_{i}^2 + W_{jerk} \cdot \frac{(u_{i+1}-u_i)^{2}}{\Delta_{s_i}} + W_{snap}\cdot \frac{(u_{i+1}-2u_i +u_{i-1})^2}{\Delta_{s_i}^2}+ W_{\text{traj}} \cdot (\underline{x_{i}}-\underline{x}_{\tau_{i}})^{2}
$$
Where $W_u$, $W_{jerk}$, $W_{snap}$ and $W_{\text{traj}}$ are weighting matrices known in advance. The problem is this cost function is not quadratic right now due to $\Delta_{s_i}$  in the denominator but I need to include it as I want to minimize first and second derivative of $\kappa$, which are approximated by the terms after $W_{jerk}$ and $W_{snap}$ in $J$.

Moreover, my state dynamics are the following ones (consider a discretized system where dS defines the amount of change between two consecutive states):

$$ \dot{x} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
           \Delta_{s_i} \cdot cos(\theta_{trailer}) \\
           \Delta_{s_i} \cdot sin(\theta_{trailer}) \\
           \Delta_{s_i} \cdot \kappa_{trailer}
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: How do you plan to apply LQR? Namely, your system dynamics is continuous time but the cost is for discrete time (or should in the system dynamics the following maybe be replaced $\dot{x}=x_{i+1}-x_i}$), and the system is nonlinear while LQR can only be used for linear systems.

Comment: The system is discretized as well, I have reformulized the question as well